# Simple dining philosopher using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, dining-philosopher

I am working on the dining philosophers program.  However I am running into a problem that my program stops before all of the philosophers have eaten, and I don't understand why. This is my code as of now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *func(int n);
pthread_t philosopher[5];
pthread_mutex_t chopstick[5];

int main()
{
     int i;
     void *msg;
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_mutex_init(&chopstick[i],NULL);
     }
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,(void *)func,(int *)i);
     }
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_join(philosopher[i],&msg);
     }
      for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
      {
          pthread_mutex_destroy(&chopstick[i]);
      }
     return 0;
}

void *func(int n)
{
     printf ("\nPhilosopher %d is thinking ",n);
     pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[n]);//when philosopher 5 is eating he takes fork 1 and fork 5
     pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);
     printf ("\nPhilosopher %d is eating ",n);
     sleep(3);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[n]);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);
     printf ("\nPhilosopher %d finished eating ",n);
}
```

Comment: Among other things, the philosophers need to grab chopsticks in a predefined order (for instance, grab the chopstick with the highest number first).

Comment: "my program stops before all of the philosophers have eaten" - isn't that exactly the behaviour you want to observe with the dining philisophers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dining Philosopher Program C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529773/dining-philosopher-program-c)

Answer (score 5):

I ran the question code on my SLES 11 server many times.  I did not observe the issue indicated in the question.

Nevertheless, you need to change your for() statements from:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
```

In any case, there are a few things that -might- be changed in the question code. *(Nothing critical to the answer)*:

- Although 'func()' is declared to return a 'void *', it does not.
- The function prototype 'void *func(int n);' can be eliminated if 'main()' is moved to the end of the file.
- It is not necessary to pass '&msg' into pthread_join()'; 'NULL' can be passed in instead, allowing the elimination of 'msg' completely.

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t philosopher[5];
pthread_mutex_t chopstick[5];

void *func(int n)
   {
   printf ("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",n);

   //when philosopher 5 is eating he takes fork 1 and fork 5
   pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[n]);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);
   printf ("Philosopher %d is eating\n",n);
   sleep(3);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[n]);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);

   printf ("Philosopher %d finished eating\n",n);

   return(NULL);
   }

int main()
   {
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_mutex_init(&chopstick[i],NULL);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,(void *)func,(void *)i);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_join(philosopher[i],NULL);

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&chopstick[i]);

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm kinda new to this. :/

Comment: @user3335367, the question code was very well done.  Don't sell yourself short.  Good luck!